# JPA query of list of Strings fails

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA-enabled, mongoDB-backed Spring Boot REST service in which I'm having trouble querying a list in the entity. They look like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639df2e83f61353766023bf9"
  },
  "body": "body1",
  "name": "name1",
  "tags": [
    "tag1"
  ],
  "_class": "ca.footeware.rest.recipes.model.Recipe"
}
```

Note that "tags" is an array of Strings.

My repository extends MongoRepository<Recipe, String>. I have two methods, the first works but the second doesn't:

```
Page<Recipe> findByNameOrBodyContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc(String name, String body, Pageable pageable);

Page<Recipe> findByNameOrBodyOrTagsContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc(String name, String body, String tags, Pageable pageable);
```

The addition of "OrTags" and the accompanying "tags" parameter causes a search for "tag" to fail. Further it seems everything after "OrTags" is ignored, i.e. the "Containing", "IgnoreCase" and "OrderBy" are lost.

What am I doing wrong?

---

OK, for those playing along at home, I made some changes I hesitate to call progress.
I saw somewhere that the problem might be the type of the list, i.e. String. So I created a record:

```
public record Tag(String value) {
  public Tag(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

And changed my entity class to:

```
public class Recipe {
  private String body;n
  @Id
  private String id;
  private List<String> images;
  private String name;
  private List<Tag> tags;
  ...
```

In mongodb's Compass app it shows its JSON as:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639e3f4b0f60a06354564152"
  },
  "body": "body1",
  "name": "name1",
  "tags": [
    {
      "value": "tag1"
    }
  ],
  "_class": "ca.footeware.rest.recipes.model.Recipe"
}
```

My repository method is now:

```
Page<Recipe> findByNameOrBodyOrTagsValueContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc(String name, String body, String tags, Pageable pageable);
```

And it works! Well kinda...if I search for the fields' exact value it works. The **ContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc** is being ignored. Not good in a search function.

Anyone have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Oh I should've mentioned I'm on Spring Boot 3 and Java 19 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct sequence of elements in the repository method is:

```
findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrBodyContainingIgnoreCaseOrTagsValueContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc
```

Not sure if my modification from List of String to List of Tag made any difference.

Comment: Just reverted some code and the List of String works fine. No need for a more complex element in entity lists.